$(u|u+v)$ construction generator matrix
I've been studying the $(u|u+v)$ construction. However, I don't understand how the generator matrix is created. If $C = \{ (u|u+v)~| u\in C_1, v\in C_2\}$ the generator matrix for $C$ is
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{G}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{G}_1 & \mathbf{G}_1 \\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{G}_2
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*},
$$
where $G_1$ is the generator matrix for $C_1$ and $G_2$ is the generator matrix for $C_2$. I cannot see how that construction is developed. Thanks :)

Related.

You get a basis for $C$ by putting together the following two collections of vectors of the shape $(u\vert u+v)$

letting $u$ range over a basis of $C_1$ while keeping $v=0$, and
letting $v$ range over a basis of $C_2$ while keeping $u=0$.

The reason this yields a basis is that

the listed vectors will be linearly independent, and
you get all the vectors as appropriate linear combinations (i.e. they span $C$).

The vectors in the first collection give you $(\mathbf{G}_1\vert\mathbf{G}_1)$, and the vectors in the second collection give you $(\mathbf{0}\vert\mathbf{G}_2)$
